# Shading an area between two points in a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do you add a shaded area between two points in a [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/index.html) plot?

In the example [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/index.html) plot below, I manually added the shaded, yellow area using [Skitch](http://www.skitch.com/). I'd like to know how to do this sans-Skitch.

[image]

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can just use the function `axvspan`.  The advantage to this is that the vertical region (or horizontal, in the case of `axhspan`) will remain shaded regardless of how you pan/zoom the plot.  There's a complete example [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/axhspan_demo.html).

See a simple example below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 500)
y = np.cos(3*x) - 2*np.cos(5*x) + 0.5*np.cos(6*x)

a = 5
b = 15

plt.axvspan(a, b, color='y', alpha=0.5, lw=0)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.savefig('shade.png', dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

That gives as a result
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The matplotlib `fill` method plots [filled polygons](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill.html).

The advantage of the `fill` method is how straight-forward it is to plot complicated polygons.  Each polygon is defined by the lists of x and y positions of its nodes.

Using the example data from nicoguaro's answer:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 500)
y = np.cos(3 * x) - 2 * np.cos(5 * x) + 0.5 * np.cos(6 * x)

border = 0.25
y_min, y_max = min(y) - border, max(y) + border

a = 5
b = 15

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.fill([a, a, b, b], [y_min, y_max, y_max, y_min], color = 'green', alpha = 0.5)
plt.ylim(ymin = y_min, ymax = y_max)
plt.show()
```

Gives the following figure:

[image]

It is not strictly necessary to set the minimum and maximum y limits as I have.  If not set, there will be a white border above and below the shaded region.